# Can vim/neovim execute a command immediately after pasting text?

Tags: vim, neovim

This probably isn't possible but figured I'd ask. I have a utility installed on my machine that lets me highlight text in one app and quickly paste it over into my terminal which has neovim open.

I'd like to automatically run some basic text commands after the paste operation to spare me the chore. Can this be done?

Comment: What basic text commands and what chores? Maybe the ability to run commands right after paste is the solution, maybe it's not.

Answer (score 2):

sure if you use `p` for pasting, you can just remap it to `p` and then your function:

```
:nnoremap p p :echo "HELLO WORLD"<CR>
```

The same should also work with `<S-Insert>`